# How to write a method for the Array Class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to add an array method to my ruby on rails 6 application

```
  class Array
    def except(value)
      self - [value].flatten
    end
  end
```

This is what I tried to add in a helper module, but I can't call the except method on arrays. What would be a way to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it under lib directory -

```
lib/array.rb
```

Also, you need to require it in `config/application.rb` file -

```
require "array.rb"
```

---

Another way to do so without requiring in the config would be to write it in an initializer:

```
config/initializers/additional_methods.rb
```